# XSD: restrict content to be equal to grandparent if it is present

Tags: xsd

Can you use an XSD to restrict the content of an XML element to be equal to its grandparent? So that this *passes* validation:

```
<pupil>
<pupilid>342424</pupilid>
<name>John Smith</name>
<assessment>
<assessmentid>1</assessmentid>
<pupilid>342424</pupilid>
</assessment>
</pupil>
```

And this *fails* validation:

```
<pupil>
<pupilid>342424</pupilid>
<name>John Smith</name>
<assessment>
<assessmentid>1</assessmentid>
<pupilid>666</pupilid>
</assessment>
</pupil>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it if you consider the above as referential integrity. One could easily say that there is redundant information, but I've also seen it due to model reuse.

This is what your XML looks like:

[image]

This is what the XSD would then look like:

[image]

And the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="pupil">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="pupilid" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="assessment">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="assessmentid" type="xsd:unsignedByte"/>
                            <xsd:element name="pupilid" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="PK">
            <xsd:selector xpath="pupilid"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="."/>
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:keyref name="FK" refer="PK">
            <xsd:selector xpath="assessment/pupilid"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="."/>
        </xsd:keyref>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Your first XML would pass validation, while the second may yield:

`Error occurred while loading [], line 8 position 3
The key sequence '666' in Keyref fails to refer to some key.
xsd-restrict-content-to-be-equal-to-grandparent-if-it-is-present.xml is XSD 1.0 invalid.`

As long as these kind of constraints can be modeled similar to what referential integrity means for database people, then key/unique and keyref can help.

For more general co-constraints, you would have to either move to XSD 1.1 or use Schematron in addition to XSD 1.0.